# Can´t close a strategy

Tags: pine-script

Can´t close a strategy. Just would like the strategy to be long when SMA 21 crossover SMA 50 and closes when crossunder.

```
strategy("Strategy1", overlay=true)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 21), sma(close, 50))
if (longCondition)  
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)  

strategy.close("Exit", crossunder(sma(close, 21), sma(close, 50)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which entry *id* you want to exit when using *strategy.close()* function. Use "*My Long Entry Id*" same as in *strategy.entry()* function:

```
strategy.close("My Long Entry Id", crossunder(sma(close, 21), sma(close, 50)))
```